# Computed property from a promise

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a ember-data model with a relationship(many-many). So there is a computed property depends on the relationship element. I need to return boolean value based on data of the relationship property.

```
isAllowed: function(){
        return this.get('allowedUsers').then(function(data){
            var user = this.get('currentUser');
            return data.contains(user);
        }.bind(this));
}.property()
```

In the above code, `isAllowed` is the computed property and `allowedUsers` is in many relation with `user` model and `async` is set as `true`. isAllowed is getting set to the promise object rather returned boolean. I even tried to create another promise object like below but no luck.

```
 isAllowed: function(){
            return new Ember.RSVP.promise(function(resolve, reject){
               this.get('allowedUsers').then(function(data){
                var user = this.get('currentUser');
                 resolve(data.contains(user));
              }.bind(this));

            }.bind(this));
    }.property()
```

How can I make sure that isAllowed is set to boolean value rather the promise object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `DS.PromiseObject`:

```
isAllowed: Ember.computed('model.users.[]', 'session.currentUser', function() {
  return DS.PromiseObject.create({
    promise: this.get('session.currentUser').then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        return false;
      }
      return this.get('model.users').isAny('id', user.get('id'));
    })
  });
})
```

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseObject.html

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
isAllowed: function(key, value){
  if (arguments.length > 1) return value; // the setter was called

  this.get('allowedUsers').then(function(data){
    var user = this.get('currentUser');
    this.set("isAllowed", data.contains(user));
  }.bind(this));

  return false;
}.property()
```

Comment: Well, I guess it is. Since you need to get a boolean value right away, you have to handle the promise behind the scenes

Comment: Would it be wrong to save an instance of `this` like `var _this = this;` and later overwrite `isAllowed` via `_this` vs binding `this` like in the example?

Comment: @jwahdatehagh Effectively it would be the same thing. OP used `bind` in his example, so I used it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If this were me, I would initialize with `false`, then set it to resolve in the `setupController` hook. For example, in your controller:

```
isAllowed: false, // Default with access denied
```

Now you can leverage your route. Routes are already juggling the model and controller, so that generally feels like the right place to resolve sideloading promises:

```
App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    //...
  },

  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    this.setUserAccess(controller, model);
    // more methods if needed...
  },

  setUserAccess (controller, model) {
    controller.get('allowedUsers').then(function(data){
      var user = controller.get('currentUser');
      controller.set("isAllowed", data.contains(user));
    });
  }
);
```

I wasn't sure where `allowedUsers` was coming from. You may need to tweak that.

You can do this either way, but I always feel a little icky when I override computed properties with a static property. Certainly nothing wrong with it, though.